# How to get the max count of rows for specific field?

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I'm new to LINQ, I have this situation:

Table 1:

[image: Table 1:]

Table 2:

[image: Table 2:]

I want to select the max count for donations from table 1 relevant to TCode and get the TDescription corresponding to the returned result.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**
I have managed to get the count for each donation type with this piece of code:

```
Dim query = (From aDonation In DBEntity.Donation_Tbls
                Group aDonation By aDonation.TCode Into myGroup = Group
                Select code = TCode, cnt = myGroup.Count)
```

**What I need is to get only one row/result for the max cnt and its code.**

Comment: I have edited your title. Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
var maxDonated = table1.GroupBy(d => d.TCode)
                .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                .FirstOrDefault().Key;  

var maxDonatedDescription = table2.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TCode == maxDonated).TDescription;
```

please check if it works, I have not tested.
I have just shown how you can do it, you should do null check etc.

VB code :
I am working on C#, so not sure if it is perfect

```
Dim maxDonated = table1.GroupBy(Function(d) d.TCode)
                 .OrderByDescending(Function(g) g.Count())
                 .FirstOrDefault().Key

Dim maxDonatedDescription = table2.FirstOrDefault(Function(t) t.TCode = maxDonated).TDescription
```

Comment: Can you please type it in VB.Net?

Comment: @Roshdy, I have added the VB code, you can try it if it helps you

Comment: I really can't map the C# to VB as well, and the one you sent is syntactically wrong. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: ohh, but if you can understand it, then it may work for you. you can try the same thing, because I am not that good on VB. Goodluck